# Calling a node in GameScene.sks from GameScene.swift error

Tags: xcode, swift3, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I've placed a Color Sprite in GameScene.sks and named it line1LightLeft and gave it the texture named arrowLeftOff.

Now I want the image to change in GameScene.swift. So I first want to connect the node in the .sks to the .swift.

```
var line1LightLeft = SKSpriteNode()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    line1LightLeft = self.childNode(withName: "arrowLeftOff") as! SKSpriteNode

}
```

I don't get any errors but when I build and run the game I get the message:
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil unwrapping an Optional value

The line of code with self.childNode in it turns red and it says:
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Off course I've tried Google but the answers I find don't change it or even give more errors. Does anyone see an error?

Grrrr, why can't I ctrl-click-drag just like in a single view application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've named the sprite 'line1LightLeft' then this line of code:

```
line1LightLeft = self.childNode(withName: "arrowLeftOff") as! SKSpriteNode
```

should read

```
line1LightLeft = self.childNode(withName: "line1LightLeft") as! SKSpriteNode
```

EDIT:

For clarification, the `withName`parameter of the `childNode`function refers to the desired node's `.name` property and not it's `.texture` property.